# Enable compression in nodejs grpc server

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node

**Is there any way to enable compression in a grpc-nodejs server?**

It seems that it's possible to implement it, since it can deflate/unzip compressed data, but cannot compress while sending the response back.

I spun up the test nodejs server, and interacted with it using a python client. I MITM-ed the interaction between the server and client using `nc` to get the number of bytes transferred, and see the effect of compression.

When I sent the `'grpc.default_compression_algorithm'` metadata while making the request through the python client, I was able to see that the data sent by the client was compressed, but the data sent back by the server was uncompressed. (`sent 815, rcvd 300324` for an echo grpc service).

Setting metadata on the nodejs server side doesn't help, it still sends uncompressed data.

The reason why I think this should be possible is because it was able to read the compressed request. Also the npm grpc package is a wrapper over a grpc binary. Running an `nm grpc_node.node | grep gzip` returns

```
0000000000306800 d grpc_stream_compression_gzip_vtable
00000000000b2fd0 t _ZL10gzip_flateP36grpc_stream_compression_context_gzipP17grpc_slice_bufferS2_PmmiPb
00000000000b3670 t _ZL25grpc_stream_compress_gzipP31grpc_stream_compression_contextP17grpc_slice_bufferS2_Pmm29grpc_stream_compression_flush
00000000000b3600 t _ZL27grpc_stream_decompress_gzipP31grpc_stream_compression_contextP17grpc_slice_bufferS2_PmmPb
00000000000b2ed0 t _ZL43grpc_stream_compression_context_create_gzip30grpc_stream_compression_method
00000000000b2e70 t _ZL44grpc_stream_compression_context_destroy_gzipP31grpc_stream_compression_context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting this worked for me.

```
let server = new grpc.Server({
    'grpc.default_compression_level': 2, // (1->Low -- 3->High)
});
```